# Speed up MySQL Multiple Single Inserts for lastrowid

Tags: python, mysql

I have 2 tables, the first:

```
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| profile_id      | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| landing_page_id | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| keyword         | varchar(2083) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| unique_key      | varchar(200)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The second looks like:

```
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| profile_id      | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| landing_page_id | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| keyword_id      | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| position        | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| impressions     | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ctr             | float      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| clicks          | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| metric_dates    | date       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

These are connected by the `id` of the first table and `keyword_id` in the second table.

At the moment, I'm inserting each `keyword` to then return the `lastrowid`. Data for the second table is then just batched together while I collect all the keyword_ids (`lastrowid`) and inserted in batches of 5,000 at the end.

As you can imagine, the bulk data at the end goes in very quickly, but the single inserts are taking some time.

The single inserts can range from a few thousand up to a million.

The class methods I wrote for these are as follows:

```
def insert_keyword(self, profile_id, landing_page_id, keyword, unique_key):
    try:
        sql = '''insert into keywords_v2
                (profile_id, landing_page_id, keyword, unique_key)
                values (%s, %s, %s, %s)
                on duplicate key
                update
                landing_page_id = values(landing_page_id)'''
        self.cursor.execute(sql, (profile_id, landing_page_id, keyword, unique_key))
        self.db.commit()
        return self.cursor.lastrowid
    except Exception as e:
        self.db.rollback()
    finally:
        self.db.close()

def insert_metrics(self, data):
    try:
        sql = '''insert into keyword_metrics_v2
                (profile_id, landing_page_id, keyword_id, position, impressions, ctr, clicks, metric_dates)
                values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''
        self.cursor.executemany(sql, data)
        self.db.commit()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        self.db.rollback()
    finally:
        self.db.close()
```

How can I speed this up?

Comment: insert in pieces of 100 rows at one time. then get the last rowid and insert the 100 rows in the second table

Comment: What and then calculate what each rowid would be?

Comment: you get the last insert_id. if you write 100 or 1000 rows in one query the 100 numbers are in order. so you know each last_insert_id - 100 or 1000 is th first